# How to fix " 3*10**(0) + 8*10**(-1) + 5*10**(-2) + 2*10**(-3) do not equal 3.852 "?

Tags: python, numbers

I have number_list ['3', '.', '8', '5', '2'] and try to transform back to 3.852 by

```
>>> 3*10**(0) + 8*10**(-1) + 5*10**(-2) + 2*10**(-3)
3.8519999999999994
```

Why i got 3.8519999999999994, not 3.852 ? How to fix it ?
Part of the calculation works independently.

```
>>> 3*10**(0)
3
>>> 8*10**(-1)
0.8
>>> 5*10**(-2)
0.05
>>> 2*10**(-3)
0.002
```

Comment: See also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). It's not clear if you are asking why, or just want to solve the problem, which is probably better solved with `float(''.join(['3', '.', '8', '5', '2']))`

Comment: The modules "decimal" and "fractions" provide other number implementations which may help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this using string concatenation and parsing the output string.

Example:

```py
number_list = ['3', '.', '8', '5', '2']
parsed_number = float("".join(number_list))
print(parsed_number)
# Output: 3.852
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results within 3 decimal points you can use a python built in function `round`

```py
expression = 3*10**(0) + 8*10**(-1) + 5*10**(-2) + 2*10**(-3)
round(expression, 3)
```